# Can I use PowerMockito in Quarkus with JUnit5?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, quarkus, powermockito

Im am currently building a Quarkus application and for unit testing I am using JUnit5. Currently I have no other option then using PowerMockito to mock my static functions but I cant seem to find the dependencies for it in my Quarkus project.

Does anyone know what the best set of dependecies should be used in a Quarkus app for PowerMockito with JUnit5?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my guess is that it won't work because PowerMock uses its own ClassLoader as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't need PowerMockito, just the capability to mock static methods. Since 2.7.x (released in 2017) Mockito community made an experimental library called `mockito-inline` for mocking static methods or final classes. Some features (e.g. static method mocking) have already merged into mockito-core.
Additionally Quarkus has extension for Mockito.

Here is a working example

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.zforgo</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-mockito-static</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.6.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Some utility class with static method

```java
package io.github.zforgo;

public class SomeStaticClass {

    public static String getSome() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Test class

```java
package io.github.zforgo;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@QuarkusTest
public class SomeStaticClassTest {

    @Test
    void nonMocked() {
        assertEquals("foo", SomeStaticClass.getSome(), "Something went wrong");
    }

    @Test
    void mocked() {
        // try-with-resources is recommended in case of scoped (temporary) mocking 
        try (var mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(SomeStaticClass.class)) {
            mocked.when(SomeStaticClass::getSome).thenReturn("bar");
            assertEquals("bar", SomeStaticClass.getSome(), "Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```